# strlen function using recursion in c

Tags: c, recursion, strlen

I'm kida new to the recursion subject and i've been trying to write the "strlen" function using recurion, thats what i tried:

```
int strlen ( char str[], int i)
{
    if ( str[i] == 0) return i+1;
    return strlen(str,i++);
}
```

and i tried something very similiar

```
int strlen( char str[], int i)
{
    if ( str[i] == 0) return 1;
    return strlen(str,i++) + 1;
}
```

and in my main function

```
int main()
{
     char word[MAX_DIGITS];
     scanf("%s",word);
     printf("%d", strlen(word,0));
     return 0;
}
```

but my program would crash whenever i run it, what am I missing? (I'm using C90 btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem starts here:

```
i++
```

This is called a postfix.
Just use `++i` or `i + 1`

Postfix sends the value and just then increments the variable. It's like writing this:

```
return strlen(str,i);
i = i + 1;
```

You have to use Prefix, which increments the variable and then sends the value. A prefix (`++i`) will act like that:

```
i = i + 1;
return strlen(str,i);
```

Or just send the value without changing the variable:

```
return strlen(str, i + 1);
```

Which, in my opinion, is the simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
size_t strlen (char* str) {
    if (*str == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return strlen (str+1) +1;
}
```

So :

- `strlen ("") == 0`
- `strlen ("a") -> strln("") + 1 == 1`
- `strlen ("he") -> strln("e") + 1) =  (strln("") + 1) + 1 == 2`

etc

Answer (score 2):

```
return strlen(str,i++);
```

You are using the wrong increment operator. `i++` means the original value of `i` is passed as argument, and then it's incremented. That means infinite recursion.

You should try `++i` instead, or better, `i + 1`.

Comment: Actually I think i+1 i clearer in this situation, but your point is valid :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the same prototype as `strlen` does.
This is how i see a strlen with recursion.

```
size_t strlen(char *str)
{
    static int i = 0;

    if (*str != '\0')
    {
        i++;
        return ft_strlen(++str);
    }
    return i;
}
```

I know it's not the best way to do it. Just my implementation.

Comment: The correct prototype for strlen is `size_t strlen(const char *s);`. And don't worry too much about the best way, since recursion can never be the best way to write this function. Using recursion for this will always be a horrible idea in real-world programming.