# How to perfom strlen recursively with a function?

Tags: c, recursion

I've made it in iterative way:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
void lol(char *s1,int *i) { 
    while(*s1!='\0') { 
        s1 = (s1 + 1); 
        *i=*i+1; 
    } 
}

void main(void) { 
    char s1[] = "hello"; 
    int i=0; 
    lol(s1,&i); 
    printf("%d", i); 
    _getch(); 
}
```

Could anyone perfome this but with recursion?

Comment: Yes, someone could. What have *you* tried doing and what is unclear/the problem?

Comment: BTW `void main(void)` has been deprecated for decades...

Comment: #Please do an effort and check on [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745442/strlen-function-using-recursion-in-c) before, this took me 10sec.

Comment: @UnholySheep,I was trying but I can't image how recursive work in this case and how to use pointers correctly with recursion.

Comment: For the length of a string, recursion is a poor application.  OK for learning, but do not use in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive strlen:

```
int mylen(char *s) 
{
    if (!*s) return 0;
    return (mylen(s+1) + 1);
}
```

Comment: this function doesn't work((

Comment: @Elvin change `char *` to `const char *` above. On what input does it not work?

Comment: Runs perfectly: `printf("%d\n",mylen("hello world"));` prints 11.